# List not visible on when sent from Spring controller to JSP

Tags: spring, jsp

To start with, here's my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/searchMedia")
public ModelAndView searchAndDisplayResource(@RequestParam String name,   @RequestParam String type){

    ResultSet rs;
    DBQuery dbQuery = new DBQuery();
    rs = dbQuery.getMediaInfo(name, type);
    if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
    //  String mediaInfoJson = omdbApiHelper.getMediaDetail(name);
        //parse the json, create the mio and persist
        return null;
    } else {
        MediaInfoHelper mediaInfoHelper = new MediaInfoHelper();
        ArrayList<MediaInfoModel> mediaList = mediaInfoHelper.getQueriedMediaList(rs);
        System.out.println(mediaList.size());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mediainfo");
        mav.addObject("mediaList",mediaList);
        return mav;
    }

}
```

And here's my JSP:

```
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <c:if test="${not empty lists}">

        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="mediaInfo" items="${mediaList}">
                <li>${mediaInfo.name}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>

    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

The size of the list is 1, for the query that I am trying. The problem is that the list just won't get displayed. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from:

```
<c:if test="${not empty lists}">
```

To:

```
<c:if test="${not empty mediaList}">
```

Comment: Damn, that's what happens when you copy without using your mind. Let me try that out, and I'll let you know.

Comment: Works! Thank you so much.